# Elasticsearch: can I aggregate and get the range / "lowest" and "highest" ips found in each bucket?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm querying a dataset where documents have a title and ip address. I want to be able to aggregate(group) on title, and return the range of ips for each aggregation/bucket.

All I can find is examples of ip range aggregation where I define the ips to aggregate on, I tried using max and min aggregations but ES doesn't like that as these are ip datatypes.

I'm trying to get an idea of what range of ips are associated with what title.